# django-registration with django-math-captcha

Tags: django, captcha

Has anyone ever successfully integrated [django-math-captcha](https://github.com/justquick/django-math-captcha) into django-registration?

I've changed the form in django-registration to be as such:

```
class RegistrationForm(MathCaptchaForm)
```

The form displays just fine, and it recognizes when I input anything other than numbers. However, it does not flag wrong answers. For example I input `2+1 = 6` and my registration completed just fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, it is because `MathCaptchaForm.clean()` was being overridden by `RegistrationForm.clean()`. I called `super()` from within `RegistrationForm.clean()` and it worked.

New code within `RegistrationForm.clean()`:

```
def clean(self):
    super(RegistrationForm, self).clean()

    if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
        if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("The two password fields didn't match."))

    return self.cleaned_data
```